# Why is Python only performing an action on the first iteration of a loop

Tags: python, loops, textblob

I have a small little loop running through the oxford dictionary looking for and printing out any word who's definition has one of the words in `search_list`

But when I run it with for example the list: `['hello', 'next', 'from'] it only runs through the loop the first time. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
print(search_list)
Oxford = open("oxford_dictionary.txt")
for word in search_list:
    for line in Oxford:
        if word in line: 
            print(line.split(' ', 1)[0])

Oxford.close()
```

Comment: Briefly: the file iterator is exhausted. If it's okay to see the results grouped by line instead of by search term, just switch the order of the loops, with `for line in Oxford: for word in search_list`.

Comment: Thanks Tiger, I think its also much more efficient to iterate this way to, so I only go through the dictionary once.

Comment: @wprins, you are ignoring that if `word in line` is actually quite a lot of work. There is an implied loop in there. It's more efficient to loop through each word of each line of the file _once_ and do an O(1) lookup in the dictionary for each.